# Как работает GroupBy

Tags: c#, запрос, linq, group-by

Всем доброго времени суток!
Прошу помочь разобраться в том, как работает GroupBy и в чем разница приведенного ниже кода.

```
class Employee {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string OfficeId { get; set; }
}

class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<Employee> Employee = new List<Employee>() {
            new Employee { Id = "1", Name = "Alex", OfficeId = "1" },
            new Employee { Id = "2", Name = "John", OfficeId = "1" },
            new Employee { Id = "1", Name = "Alex", OfficeId = "2" },
            new Employee { Id = "2", Name = "John", OfficeId = "2" },
            new Employee { Id = "2", Name = "John", OfficeId = "3" },
        };

        var result1 = Employee.GroupBy(p => new { p.Id, p.Name });
        var result2 = Employee.GroupBy(p => new Person { Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name });
    }
}
```

В случае с result1 создается коллекция с подобным типом `IEnumerable<IGrouping<AnonymousType<string, string>, Employee>>` где имеются вде записи с ключами Id и Name. Элемент, где Id = "1", Name = "Alex" имеет две записи, элемент, где Id = "2", Name = "John" имеет соответственно три записи.

Здесь у меня особо вопросов нет и структура объекта такая, какой я и ожидал ее увидеть, но мне понадобилось данный объект передать в метод в качестве аргумента и я создал класс Person, чтобы он заменял анонимный тип.

В result2 создается коллекция примерно вот такая коллекция `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Person, Employee>>` и я могу явно указать тип, который метод должен принимать. Проблема в том, что тут создался список с пятью элементами (ключами) и каждый элемент имеет по одному значению, чего я не ожидал и не могу понять почему так происходит.

Буду благодарен, если объяснят почему идет такая разница результатов, если вместо анонимного типа в GroupBy указать пользовательский тип и как сделать, чтобы получить объект с структурой данных как в result1, но с указанием пользовательского типа.

P.S. Если в GroupBy указать группировку по одному полю (например Id), то результат будет, что и в result1 только ключ будет состоять из строки, но как быть когда ключ должен представлять из себя объект с несколькими свойствами?

Comment: Потому что для анонимных типов автоматически генерируется код Equals, который учитывает все поля, а для класса вы этот метод не написали, поэтому по умолчанию они сравниваются по ссылке

Comment: Всё очень просто - поглядите, что вернет вот это сравнение `new Employee { Id = "1", Name = "Alex", OfficeId = "1" } == new Employee { Id = "1", Name = "Alex", OfficeId = "1" }`

Comment: @АндрейNOP имхо, достойно ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для анонимных типов компилятор автоматически генерирует методы `Equals` и `GetHashCode`, которые:

> определяются через методы `Equals` и `GetHashCode` свойств, два экземпляра одного и того же анонимного типа равны, только если равны их свойства.

цитата отсюда: [Анонимные типы (Руководство по программированию в C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

Поэтому следующий код выведет `True`:

```
var x = new { Id = 1, Name = "Ivan" };
var y = new { Id = 1, Name = "Ivan" };
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));
```

В классе же `Person` метод `Equals` не переопределен, поэтому используется реализация из базового класса `Object`, которая сравнивает ссылки.

Ссылки на разные экземпляры, конечно, не равны, поэтому такой код вернет `False`:

```
var x = new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Ivan" };
var y = new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Ivan" };
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));
```

Таким образом, группировка во втором случае создаст отдельную группу для каждого экземпляра `Person`.